# How to show that two expressions containing 2-dimensional sums with different iterators are equal

Tags: summation, infinity, substitution

I am trying to prove that these two expressions are equal (I verified numerically) but it's not obvious to me at first sight why they are (might be to some).

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^k{f(i,k-i)}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^\infty{f(i,j)}$$

It's a simple substitution of one iterator with another ($j=k-i$) but I'm not sure how to make that substitution when they are iterators.

Could someone please explain why this is evident or provide a method of elaboration of some sort that shows it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing $k=k_0$ at the left hand side we have as inner sum
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{k_0}f(i,k_0-i)=f(0,k_0)+f(1,k_0-1)+\cdots+f(k_0,0)
\end{align*}
which      is    a  section of  a  minor diagonal.  On  the  other hand the right hand  side  gives   for  $j=j_0$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i,j_0)=f(0,j_0)+f(1,j_0)+f(2,j_0)+\cdots
\end{align*}
the vertical half-line starting at $(0,j_0)$.

> Assuming the  double series is *[unconditionally convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconditional_convergence)* we can rearrange the terms and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i,j)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{{i+j=k}\atop{i,j\geq 0}}f(i,j)\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^kf(i,k-i)\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we introduce an index variable $k\geq 0$ and collect terms $f(i,j)$ with $i+j=k$.
- In (2) we get rid of the index $j$ by using $i+j=k$.

Comment: This is tremendous!  Thanks.  I need to work through it.

Comment: @Bill: You're welcome.